# Struggling to map a relationship with NHibernate

Tags: nhibernate, nhibernate-mapping, foreign-keys

I'm working with 2 tables, Employees and a table called EmployeeGroups as follows. I've left out most of the unrelevant columns below. I'm struggling to map the foreign key relationship. Its a one-to-one relationship where not every EmployeeId in the Employees table will exist in the EmployeeGroups table. I'm wondering how to setup the EmployeeId relationship in my mapping files below?

Employees

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Employees](
[EmployeeId] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
[ForeName] [nvarchar](20) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI NOT NULL,
[SurName] [nvarchar](20) COLLATE Latin1_General_CI_AI NOT NULL,

CONSTRAINT [PK_Employees_1] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EmployeeId] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]
```

EmployeeGroups

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeGroups](
[GroupId] [int] NULL,
[EmployeeId] [int] NOT NULL,
[Active] [int] NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_EmployeeGroups] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [EmployeeId] ASC
)WITH (IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

USE [DemoDEV]
GO
ALTER TABLE [dbo].[EmployeeGroups]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT     
[FK_EmployeeGroups_Employees] FOREIGN KEY([EmployeeId])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Employees] ([EmployeeId])
```

My Employees mapping file so far

```
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
<class name="AdaptiveMaintenance.Core.Domain.Employee, AdaptiveMaintenance.Core" table="Employees" lazy="false">
    <id name="ID" column="EmployeeId">
        <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>
    <property name="Forename" column="ForeName" not-null="true"/>
    <property name="Surname" column="SurName" not-null="true"/>

</class>
</hibernate-mapping>
```

My EmployeeGroups mapping file so far looks like this

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="AdaptiveMaintenance.Core.Domain.EmployeeGroup, AdaptiveMaintenance.Core" table="EmployeeGroups" lazy="false">
      <id name="ID" column="EmployeeId">
      <generator class="foreign" />
    </id>

    <property name="Active" column="Active" />
</class>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should not only consider how to map the db model, you should always think about the class model: how should it look like?

This creates a reference from the EmployeeGroup to Employee.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<hibernate-mapping xmlns="urn:nhibernate-mapping-2.2">
  <class name="AdaptiveMaintenance.Core.Domain.EmployeeGroup, AdaptiveMaintenance.Core" table="EmployeeGroups" lazy="false">
    <id name="ID" column="GroupId">
      <generator class="assigned" />
    </id>

    <property name="Active" column="Active" />
    <many-to-one name="Employee" class="Employee" column="EmployeeId"/>
</class>
```

When you have a one-to-one relation an try to couple primary key, why is there a GroupId? I made it an independent primary key.

BTW, if you are creating a new database model it is easier to design the classes first, map them afterwards and create the schema using `SchemaExport`.